# Diffuse measure space as a product of $[0;1]$ and another diffuse measure space

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions

The title speaks of itself. How far is an arbitrary finite diffuse measure space from being **almost** isomorphic to a product of $[0;1]$ with another diffuse measure space? What would be reasonable sufficient conditions? I need only almost isomorphism because I am interested in analysis of $L^p$-functions. Thank you.

Comment: Google Maharam's Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Maharam's theorem is about equivalence, i.e., algebraic isomorphism of the corresponding Banach algebras, I think, which says little about the isomorphism of the underlying measure spaces.

Comment: To build on Bill Johnson's remark, there is a representation theorem of Mahram of finite measure algebras (basically, measure spaces mod zero-sets). It is noteworthy that for $L^p$-spaces, only the measure algebra is relevant. Diffuseness is a property not represented in a measure algebra, being nonatomic is.

Comment: Do you thus claim that every finite non-atomic localizable measure space is almost isomorphic to a product of [0;1] and another such measure space? If yes, could you, please, provide a reference to a statement of this kind. It is hard for me to translate the Maharam's measure algebra results into isomorphisms of the measure spaces. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a $L^p$-space based on a nonatomic finite measure space (they are automatically localizable), then every measure space with the same measure algebra will do, the resulting $L^p$ space will be isometric, with order-preserving isometry. In particular, you can use by Maharam's theorem, a countable convex combination of infinite products of $[0,1]$ (using, if needed, the fact that $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ are isomorphic). But then, you can represent the space as the product of $[0,1]$ with a countable convex combination of products of $[0,1]$.

Comment: I still can't see the point. I know that $L^p$ spaces will be isometric, but the isomorphism of $L^p$ spaces alone does not yield an isomorphism of the measure spaces. By saying that I am interested in $L^p$ spaces I don't mean that the space is the only object I work with. I do need to work with the measure space itself. I just mean that an almost isomorphism would already do, i.e., a full measure subspace of my measure space being isomorphic to $[0;1]$ times another space. I am looking for an almost isomorphism of measure spaces, not an isomorphism of whatever algebras or function spaces.

Comment: Do you mean by "almost isomorphism" a measure preserving bimeasurable bijection between full-measure (measurable?) subsets of two measure spaces?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the common definition of that term, isn't it?

Comment: Take your underlying space to be $[0,1]$, use the $\sigma$-algebra of countable and co-countable subsets, and the 0-1-valued probability measure that puts probability 0 on countable sets and probability 1 on uncountable sets. It is diffuse and certainly nothing like a product of $[0,1]$ with the uniform distribution and anything else.

Comment: Not that I am absolutely sure in the non-existence of an **almost** isomorphism between the two, but neither I expected the answer to be always positive. That's why I am asking how far it is from the general case, and what would be sufficient conditions. Do you think I could improve the question to avoid further confusion?

Comment: I think for general measure spaces, the answer is going to be very complicated because general measure spaces can look extremely complicated.If you are willing to make strong assumptions such as your measure space being (standard Borel)(https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Standard_Borel_space) you will get an actual isomorphism.

Comment: Suppose that the underlying measurable space is standard Borel, but the measure on it is is neither inner nor outer regular, just a Borel measure. Do you claim that I have an almost isomorphism with $[0;1]$ times another finite standard Borel measure space? If yes, I would appreciate details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a result that covers "most" finite measure spaces encountered in applications. Let $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ be a *standard Borel space*, that is $\Sigma$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for some separable completely metrizable topology on $\Omega$. Let $\mu$ be any finite diffuse measure on $(\Omega,\Sigma)$, we can take it without loss of generality to be a probability measure (the trivial case of the zero-measure is excluded). By Theorem 16 in Section 5 of Chapter 15 of *Real Analysis* by Royden (3rd Ed.), such $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ must be isomorphic to $[0,1]$ with the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Lebesgue measure. But by the same theorem and the fact that the product $\sigma$-algebra for the product of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of two separable metrizable spaces is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the topological product, $[0,1]\otimes[0,1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the product of Lebesgue measure with itself is too isomorphic with $[0,1]$ and therefore with $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$. This shows that the latter space can be written as a product with $[0,1]$.

To see how bad things might be for general measurable spaces, one can use the set-theoretic assumption that there is a diffuse probability measure defined on all subsets of [0,1]. By a result of Solovay, this is consistent if measurable cardinals are consistent. But since many subsets of $[0,1]$ are not Borel- or Lebesgue measurable, any product of $[0,1]$ in the usual sense with any other measure space will contain a lot of nonmeasurable sets. This precludes the existence of any almost isomorphism

Comment: Btw, which edition of Royden&Fitzpatrick are you referring to? I think I am looking into the fourth, and Chapter 15 is "Compactness Regained: The Weak Topology" which is unrelated.

Comment: I just noted that it was the 3rd-pre-Fitzpatrick-edition. To my horror, I noted that the 4th edition is missing this material.

Comment: Is the same result true for arbitrary products? (Or, at least countable products of Probability measures)